# How to use an android phone as computer speaker

Tags: android, speakers

Is there a way to use a plugged in android device as usb computer speaker?

Comment: You could use bluetooth... ?

Comment: I am not sure , but it is not possible.You can use computer speaker as your phone speaker but vice-versa is not possible.